# How facebook renders its pages so fast

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, menu, history

I was using facebook and found the following features appended into their left vertical menu.

- pages load so fast
- pages do have its back button enabled
- only a part of page reloads.

Can anyone put some idea into "How to implement it???"

Comment: "only a part of page reloads" are ajax requests.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found out the solution. They use caching technology extensively with jQuery history plugin which enables history hence making it search engine friendly.

Can be found here
http://itswadesh.wordpress.com/2012/03/29/facebook-type-vertical-navigation-menu-created-with-jquery/

Comment: This is just a tiny bit of the reason why facebook is fast. Not a full answer

Answer (score 4):

You will want to use this type of paradigm for getting the best user experience.

**AJAX is your friend**

Only send down the minimal information you need to get the outline of the page displayed to the user.

```
<html>
<head>
...scripts, meta, css etc...
</head>
<body>
<h1>Facebook Info</h1>
<div id=facebook-info>
<p>loading...</p>
</div>

<h1>Twitter Info</h1>
<div id=twitter-info>
<p>loading...</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Then in each of the content sections (that you have yet to load) have a spinner.

In the loading of your javascript (I'm abbreviating for sake of clarity...see http://jQuery.com/ for more info on their ajax calls), you can make calls to specific php pages that spit out some JSON.  This is where the real work happens and takes the time.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax('/content/getFacebookInfo.php',displayFacebookContent);
   $.ajax('/content/getTwitterInfo.php',displayTwitterContent);
});
</script>
```

Then in the displayFacebookContent and displayTwitterContent callback functions, this is where you build the content for the DOM dynamically.

```
<script>
var displayTwitterContent = function(response) {
  var html = "<ul>";
  foreach(var i in response.posts) {
     html += "<li>" + response.posts[i].message + "</li>";
  }

  html += "</ul>";
  $('#titter-info).append(html);
};
</script>
```

Again, this is abbreviated to show the concept, you will have to flesh out the scripting and also build the php handlers that respond with JSON objects.

By offloading the hard work to the AJAX handlers the main HTML is served down quickly and the user is happy.  By the time his eyes move around the page, some of the AJAX calls will have completed and you'll have dynamically inserted useable data into the DOM and they'll see it.

It's kinda like google's search as you type, it's making an AJAX call back to the server and grabbing content for you to display in real time before you even click submit.

Also research into server-side caching at the application level as well as the webserver level.  There's also some caching you can do at the network level too.

Comment: Yes. you are very true. But in this case, the browser history does not work(back button) as well as its not very search engine friendly

Answer (score 1):

I am not extremely familiar with the Facebook internals anymore but there are ways and technologies for these things:

- If you look at the source you will see that in a normal environment Facebook loads only JavaScript source files. What fast JavaScript heavy applications do is usually load the static compressed JavaScript (including view files) and then only request the dynamic Data in JSON and then render it on the client. My favorite is still the really fast compiled [EJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.EJS).
- In HTML5 ready browsers they probably use the [HTML 5 history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). The generated URL also point to a static page so when requested directly you don't loose any real information. As a fallback you can do hash based history which still keeps the back button working.
- This is simply done using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)

Answer (score 0):

Between all infrastructure, they use [Cassandra](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=24413138919), [Memcached](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=39391378919), PHP compiled in C++ and others. [Here](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Infrastructure-at-Facebook) a complete description of Facebook infra.